# Extend video by exactly one frame using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the Low Resolution Video files created by a GoPro camera as proxy videos to the HVEC clips for video editing. I'm running into a slight issue in which the camera seems to cut the last frame from these low resolution videos. I'm attempting to fix this issue by grabbing the last frame and then attempting to concatenate it to the proxy video while also preserving the start timecode.

So far I was able to run the following to grab a screenshot of the last frame:

```
ffmpeg -sseof -1 -i VIDEO_PROXY.MP4 -update 1 -q:v 1 last.jpg
```

Everything else I've found is to create a video of the image for N seconds and then concatenate it to this proxy video, but this is adding more than one frame and messing up the time codes.

I'm thinking there is probably a straightway of doing what I need using `ffmpeg`?